# Misbehaviour of ParseUser.logout()

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, logout

Write a small code snippet in which ParseUser is logged out after some condition is satisfied. Sometime it works perfectly and sometime it throws an classcastexpection shown below

> java.lang.classcastexception: org.json.jsonobject$1 cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.string

I am not able to figure out why this is happening?

This is my code snippet:-

```
ParseUser currUser1 = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currUser1.put("isLogin", false);
currUser1.saveInBackground();
Log.d("UserToLogout", currUser1.getUsername());

int counter=0;
while(counter<11) {
    if (currUser1.getBoolean("isLogin")) {
        Log.d("bit", String.valueOf(currUser1.getBoolean("isLogin")));
        counter = counter + 1;
    } else {
        Log.d("bit_0", String.valueOf(currUser1.getBoolean("isLogin")));
        ParseUser.logOut();
        break;
    }
}
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks

Comment: At what line do you get the exception, where is the input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is (most certainly) due to the fact that you're calling `currUser1.saveInBackground();` and you're not waiting for its result before `ParseUser.logOut();`.

To better see if that's the case try changing

```
currUser1.saveInBackground();
```

to

```
currUser1.save();
```